# Changing font family on TikZ text decoration crashes pdflatex

Tags: tikz-decorations

I'm using TikZ version 3.1.5b and pdftex version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (got that from the .log file). I want to fit some text to a circle, but I want to use the Trajan font, so I use the commands `\fontfamily{trjn}\selectfont`. Here's a MnWE (non-working).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw%
[
postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
                text along path, 
                text={Some text to fill out the circle so as to serve as an example {${\cdot}$}}
            }, 
            font=\normalsize, 
%           align=fit to path
        }
]
(0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{minipage}  
%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw%
[
postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
        text along path, 
        text={\fontfamily{trjn}\selectfont SOME TEXT TO FILL OUT THE CIRCLE SO AS TO SERVE AS AN EXAMPLE{${\cdot}$}}
    }, 
    font=\normalsize, 
    %           align=fit to path
}
]
(0,0) circle (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

When I compile (I use TeXstudio, just in case this is relevant) it hangs on the process and I have to cancel; when I do, I get the error `Error: Command crashed: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "text-along-path".tex`. If I comment the code for generating the same figure but with the Trajan font it works; well, just as long as I also comment the `align=fit to path` line, which also puzzles me because according to the manual for my version (page 658) this is the call for fitting the text to the path, but it doesn't work (should I post a separate question for that?).

I also think it is important to mention that if I use braces for the change of font, i.e. write `text={{\fontfamily{trjn}\selectfont SOME TEXT TO FILL OUT THE CIRCLE SO AS TO SERVE AS AN EXAMPLE{${\cdot}$}}` the document compiles, but the text doesn't bend around the circle (which for me makes a lot of sense from my short experience with TikZ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the font information in `|...|`, i.e. the initial font delimiters (see the pgfmanual v3.1.5 on p. 657)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw%
[
postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
                text along path, 
                text={Some text to fill out the circle so as to serve as an example {${\cdot}$}}
            }, 
            font=\normalsize, 
%           align=fit to path
        }
]
(0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{minipage}  
%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw%
[
postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
        text along path, 
        text={|\fontfamily{trjn}\selectfont| SOME TEXT TO FILL OUT THE CIRCLE SO AS TO SERVE AS AN EXAMPLE{${\cdot}$}}
    }, 
    font=\normalsize, 
    %           align=fit to path
}
]
(0,0) circle (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Added `\usepackage{ae}` to really make use of the font, as pointed out by the OP.

Comment: Well, now it compiles; still, that font (the text in all-caps) is not the Trajan font. I shall read the manual, but is there any way of applying the selected font to the text?
EDIT: also, what about the `align=fit to path` line? Should I make it into a separate question?

Comment: @ÓscarGuajardo I do not have your font installed. If you have it and can use it outside of Ti*k*Z, it will also appear in the decorated text.

Comment: My bad: typesetting the Trajan requieres loading the `ae` package; thanks, mate!

Comment: @ÓscarGuajardo Thanks! I didn't know that. Learned something new.